# using database openhelper in another activity

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

in openhelper I have createQuestionDb(). How can I use this activity in another class (preferences) ?

```
public class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
 public OpenHelper(Context context, final boolean questionDb) {
        super(context, dbName, null, 1);
}
         public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ... " );
         createQuestionDb(db,myvalue);

        }

     public void createQuestionDb(SQLiteDatabase db, String myvalue ) {
     ContentValues _Values = new ContentValues();
    _Values.put("Text", myvalue);  
    db.insert("table", null, _Values);   

    }
}
```

class that will use openhelper :

```
public class Preferences extends Activity {

public void insertdata () {
createQuestionDb();
}
```

Comment: We need to know your constuctor and classname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you are doing, but it looks like you are extending SQLiteOpenHelper so try a slightly different approach:

```
public void createQuestionDb(String myvalue) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues _Values = new ContentValues();
    _Values.put("Text", myvalue);  
    db.insert("table", null, _Values);
    db.close();
}
```

Now you can call `createQuestionDb(string)` in any class you want.

---

To prevent recursive calls add the first insert manually to `onCreate()`:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ... " );
    ContentValues _Values = new ContentValues();
    _Values.put("Text", myvalue);  
    db.insert("table", null, _Values);   
}
```

Comment: (modified my codes) thanks, its what I want to make. But when I try it in onCreate  "get writable database called recursively" error appears. is there any solution for it?